# SPService cascading dropdown Issue with custom form

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, spservices, cascading

I implemented cascading dropDown for my list with default form *newform.aspx* and it works fine.

But if I try to create custom form by sharepoint designer, and when i I implemented cascading dropDown for fields in this form, the filter doesn't work

so , could you help me to implemented cascading dropDown for custom form
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can you post your code please?

Comment: This code for the default form newform.aspx , and it works fine
as the same code for my customform.aspx , but its not works

Comment: `<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="......../jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script> <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="......../jquery.SPServices-2014.02.min.js"></script> <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> $(document).ready(function() { $().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({ relationshipList: "Regions", relationshipListParentColumn: "country", relationshipListChildColumn: "Title", relationshipListSortColumn: "ID", parentColumn: "Country Required Field", childColumn: "Region Required Field", debug: true}); </script>`

Answer (score 1):

@taher: The reason the function isn't working on your custom form is most likely that the DOM is different. SPCascadeDropdowns looks for very specific elements in the page based on the DOM for the standard forms.

Once you've customized the form, you're pretty much on your own. You can always write something to do the cascading yourself, or fork the SPServices code to look for the elements you have in your customized page.

Comment: @Mr.Marc: Could you please help me to solve this Issue ? with Thanks

Comment: using jquery.SPServices-0.7.2.min.js , and jquery-1.8.2.js ,, the SPServices code works fine with default and custom forms , but the problem with this release is not works for the required fields , so i am using the jquery.SPServices-2014.02.min.js release with jquery-1.11.3.min.js ,,, so this release solve the filter with required fields , but it have Issue with Custom forms

Comment: @taher: I explained what you need to do above. I can't really fix it for you; you'll need to do some coding. And you *definitely* should be using 2014.02 in all cases. Nothing older.

Comment: i am running SharePoint Online, and i am using jquery.SPServices-2014.02.min.js with jquery-1.11.3.js

Simply we tried using SPCascadeDropdowns documented with Countries,Regions And States Example at the link below : https://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=$().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns&referringTitle=Documentation

i faced an issue when I tried to make the fields (Country and Region) on the state list as required, the SPCascadeDropdowns works fine only for the standared Forms (NewForm.aspx , EditFrom.aspx ) But its not work for the customForm.aspx

Comment: And if we change the Fields As non-required , the SPCascadeDropdowns works fine for the standards and customs Forms

Comment: Ok, in this latter case, look at the element title, which should be something like "columnName Required Field". 2014.02 should handle that, but if it isn't, try using "columnName Required Field" as the columnName. See my post http://sympmarc.com/2014/01/23/office-365-update-changes-display-name-on-required-fields/

Comment: `<tr>
<td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel">
<H3 class="ms-standardheader">
<nobr>Region<span class="ms-formvalidation"> *</span>
</nobr>
</H3>
</td>
<td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody">
<SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="ff3{$Pos}" ControlMode="New" FieldName="Region" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('i',concat('ff3',$Pos),'Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@Region')}"/>
<SharePoint:FieldDescription runat="server" id="ff3description{$Pos}" FieldName="Region" ControlMode="New"/>
</td>
</tr>`

i can't Find Title Element

Comment: i am using .2014.02 , its not handle that

Comment: Do yo mean by using "columnName Required Field" as the columnName ,,, to make the column Title Name as "columnName Required Field" ?

Comment: You're looking at the code in the page, not in the browser. Look at what is rendered - JavaScript runs there.

Comment: the column name similler in the two forms , columnName Required Field (Required Field in my language Arabic )
the code of standard newform.aspx as same as the code of customform.aspx , there is no different , sorry Mark , i am starter in sharepoint , Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure I can help you much more. It's about making sure the markup in the custom form is the same in structure as the out of the box forms. Without knowing what customizations you're doing, it's not really possible for me to help. It's less a SharePoint thing and more a JavaScript thing once the page is in the browser.

Comment: @MarcDAnderson I have the exact same issue and have opened the custom (inforPath) newifs.aspx->ForrmResource.aspx in IE browser.  Can send this over if required. SPCascadedDropDown works fine in NewForm.aspx

Comment: Also I have compared in debugger the default v InfoPath forms .. The latter is a almost unrecognisable . bv_vnJYSWRUIT1AdSpK_0\u0022\u003e\u003ctd class=\u0022h_vnJYSWRUIT1AdSpK_0 l_vnJYSWRUIT1AdSpK_0 ay_vnJYSWRUIT1AdSpK_0\u0022\u003e\u003ch4 class=\u0022n_vnJYSWRUIT1AdSpK_0 bv_vnJYSWRUIT1AdSpK_0 inheritFontFamily\u0022\u003e\u003cspan class=\u0022b0_vnJYSWRUIT1AdSpK_0\u0022\u003e\u003cspan class=\u0022az_vnJYSWRUIT1AdSpK_0\u0022\u003e\u003cspan class=\u0022a0_vnJYSWRUIT1AdSpK_0\u0022\u003eLocation Department\u003c\u002fspan\u003e\u003c\u002fspan\u003e\u003c\

Comment: @westerdaled: The DOM for Infopath forms is nothing like the out-of-the-box forms, so the SPServices value-added functions will not work there.

Comment: @MarcDAnderson Thanks. That was the conclusion I came to so porting the filtering to InfoPath cascaded dropdowns . Not as nice ;-(